# Material colour not animating

Tags: animation

I rendered an animation and I have this issue: the material colour in the render doesn't animate as it does in the viewport. As you can see on the picture, the eyes are black with a turquoise middle - 2 materials black and turquoise (turquoise below in the stack assigned to only some faces). This middle part I animated, I put keyframes in the beginning and end of the animation, so it gradually lights up and dims out, keyframes on the color value. But in the render this middle part is ON the whole time, it doesn't animate in and out. What could be wrong with this?

Also I noticed, that this turquoise middle is rendered sort of as a post effect. While rendering I can observe that the eyes are rendered black, and only after a moment they are filled with the blue color. What is happening here? As if it's rendered in a layer on top.

I'm using Blender Internal 2.75a.

[image: Robot's Eyes]

Comment: You'll probably have to post the .blend file, or at least give us a screenshot showing the Curves window showing the keyframes for the material.

Comment: I wanted to prepare the scene for upload, and I noticed my mistake. I forgot to animate the emit property as well with the color. Sorry :-)